# How to put an image in the Activex Control Button

Tags: image, delphi, activex

I am not sure how I am going to make a procedure to put the image in
the button, It seems no Tbitbtn or TspeedButton in the activex control
wizard, so when the button is stretch the image also stretched.

The project .dpr

```
library ButtonXControl1;

uses
  ComServ,
  ButtonXControl1_TLB in 'ButtonXControl1_TLB.pas',
  ButtonImpl1 in 'ButtonImpl1.pas' {ButtonX: CoClass},
  About1 in 'About1.pas' {ButtonXAbout};

{$E ocx}

exports
  DllGetClassObject,
  DllCanUnloadNow,
  DllRegisterServer,
  DllUnregisterServer;

{$R *.TLB}

{$R *.RES}

begin
end.
```

The project implementation:

```
unit ButtonImpl1;

{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}

interface

uses
  Windows, ActiveX, Classes, Controls, Graphics, Menus, Forms, StdCtrls,
  ComServ, StdVCL, AXCtrls, ButtonXControl1_TLB;

type
  TButtonX = class(TActiveXControl, IButtonX)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FDelphiControl: TButton;
    FEvents: IButtonXEvents;
    procedure ClickEvent(Sender: TObject);
    procedure KeyPressEvent(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure DefinePropertyPages(DefinePropertyPage: TDefinePropertyPage); override;
    procedure EventSinkChanged(const EventSink: IUnknown); override;
    procedure InitializeControl; override;
    function DrawTextBiDiModeFlagsReadingOnly: Integer; safecall;
    function Get_AlignDisabled: WordBool; safecall;
    function Get_Cancel: WordBool; safecall;
    function Get_Caption: WideString; safecall;
    function Get_Default: WordBool; safecall;
    function Get_DoubleBuffered: WordBool; safecall;
    function Get_DragCursor: Smallint; safecall;
    function Get_DragMode: TxDragMode; safecall;
    function Get_Enabled: WordBool; safecall;
    function Get_Font: IFontDisp; safecall;
    function Get_Visible: WordBool; safecall;
    function Get_VisibleDockClientCount: Integer; safecall;
    function Get_WordWrap: WordBool; safecall;
    function IsRightToLeft: WordBool; safecall;
    function UseRightToLeftReading: WordBool; safecall;
    function UseRightToLeftScrollBar: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure _Set_Font(var Value: IFontDisp); safecall;
    procedure AboutBox; safecall;
    procedure InitiateAction; safecall;
    procedure Set_Cancel(Value: WordBool); safecall;
    procedure Set_Caption(const Value: WideString); safecall;
    procedure Set_Default(Value: WordBool); safecall;
    procedure Set_DoubleBuffered(Value: WordBool); safecall;
    procedure Set_DragCursor(Value: Smallint); safecall;
    procedure Set_DragMode(Value: TxDragMode); safecall;
    procedure Set_Enabled(Value: WordBool); safecall;
    procedure Set_Font(const Value: IFontDisp); safecall;
    procedure Set_Visible(Value: WordBool); safecall;
    procedure Set_WordWrap(Value: WordBool); safecall;
    procedure SetSubComponent(IsSubComponent: WordBool); safecall;
  end;

implementation

uses ComObj, About1;

{ TButtonX }

procedure TButtonX.DefinePropertyPages(DefinePropertyPage: TDefinePropertyPage);
begin
  {TODO: Define property pages here.  Property pages are defined by calling
    DefinePropertyPage with the class id of the page.  For example,
      DefinePropertyPage(Class_ButtonXPage); }
end;

procedure TButtonX.EventSinkChanged(const EventSink: IUnknown);
begin
  FEvents := EventSink as IButtonXEvents;
end;

procedure TButtonX.InitializeControl;
begin
  FDelphiControl := Control as TButton;
  FDelphiControl.OnClick := ClickEvent;
  FDelphiControl.OnKeyPress := KeyPressEvent;
end;

function TButtonX.DrawTextBiDiModeFlagsReadingOnly: Integer;
begin
  Result := FDelphiControl.DrawTextBiDiModeFlagsReadingOnly;
end;

function TButtonX.Get_AlignDisabled: WordBool;
begin
  Result := FDelphiControl.AlignDisabled;
end;

function TButtonX.Get_Cancel: WordBool;
begin
  Result := FDelphiControl.Cancel;
end;

function TButtonX.Get_Caption: WideString;
begin
  Result := WideString(FDelphiControl.Caption);
end;

function TButtonX.Get_Default: WordBool;
begin
  Result := FDelphiControl.Default;
end;

function TButtonX.Get_DoubleBuffered: WordBool;
begin
  Result := FDelphiControl.DoubleBuffered;
end;

function TButtonX.Get_DragCursor: Smallint;
begin
  Result := Smallint(FDelphiControl.DragCursor);
end;

function TButtonX.Get_DragMode: TxDragMode;
begin
  Result := Ord(FDelphiControl.DragMode);
end;

function TButtonX.Get_Enabled: WordBool;
begin
  Result := FDelphiControl.Enabled;
end;

function TButtonX.Get_Font: IFontDisp;
begin
  GetOleFont(FDelphiControl.Font, Result);
end;

function TButtonX.Get_Visible: WordBool;
begin
  Result := FDelphiControl.Visible;
end;

function TButtonX.Get_VisibleDockClientCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FDelphiControl.VisibleDockClientCount;
end;

function TButtonX.Get_WordWrap: WordBool;
begin
  Result := FDelphiControl.WordWrap;
end;

function TButtonX.IsRightToLeft: WordBool;
begin
  Result := FDelphiControl.IsRightToLeft;
end;

function TButtonX.UseRightToLeftReading: WordBool;
begin
  Result := FDelphiControl.UseRightToLeftReading;
end;

function TButtonX.UseRightToLeftScrollBar: WordBool;
begin
  Result := FDelphiControl.UseRightToLeftScrollBar;
end;

procedure TButtonX._Set_Font(var Value: IFontDisp);
begin
  SetOleFont(FDelphiControl.Font, Value);
end;

procedure TButtonX.AboutBox;
begin
  ShowButtonXAbout;
end;

procedure TButtonX.ClickEvent(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if FEvents <> nil then FEvents.OnClick;
end;

procedure TButtonX.InitiateAction;
begin
  FDelphiControl.InitiateAction;
end;

procedure TButtonX.KeyPressEvent(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  TempKey: Smallint;
begin
  TempKey := Smallint(Key);
  if FEvents <> nil then FEvents.OnKeyPress(TempKey);
  Key := Char(TempKey);
end;

procedure TButtonX.Set_Cancel(Value: WordBool);
begin
  FDelphiControl.Cancel := Value;
end;

procedure TButtonX.Set_Caption(const Value: WideString);
begin
  FDelphiControl.Caption := TCaption(Value);
end;

procedure TButtonX.Set_Default(Value: WordBool);
begin
  FDelphiControl.Default := Value;
end;

procedure TButtonX.Set_DoubleBuffered(Value: WordBool);
begin
  FDelphiControl.DoubleBuffered := Value;
end;

procedure TButtonX.Set_DragCursor(Value: Smallint);
begin
  FDelphiControl.DragCursor := TCursor(Value);
end;

procedure TButtonX.Set_DragMode(Value: TxDragMode);
begin
  FDelphiControl.DragMode := TDragMode(Value);
end;

procedure TButtonX.Set_Enabled(Value: WordBool);
begin
  FDelphiControl.Enabled := Value;
end;

procedure TButtonX.Set_Font(const Value: IFontDisp);
begin
  SetOleFont(FDelphiControl.Font, Value);
end;

procedure TButtonX.Set_Visible(Value: WordBool);
begin
  FDelphiControl.Visible := Value;
end;

procedure TButtonX.Set_WordWrap(Value: WordBool);
begin
  FDelphiControl.WordWrap := Value;
end;

procedure TButtonX.SetSubComponent(IsSubComponent: WordBool);
begin
  FDelphiControl.SetSubComponent(IsSubComponent);
end;

initialization
  TActiveXControlFactory.Create(
    ComServer,
    TButtonX,
    TButton,
    Class_ButtonX,
    1,
    '{B3400964-1AFE-45E8-A3ED-1286AE605314}',
    0,
    tmApartment);
end.
```

The TLB?

```
unit ButtonXControl1_TLB;

// ************************************************************************ //
// WARNING                                                                    
// -------                                                                    
// The types declared in this file were generated from data read from a       
// Type Library. If this type library is explicitly or indirectly (via        
// another type library referring to this type library) re-imported, or the   
// 'Refresh' command of the Type Library Editor activated while editing the   
// Type Library, the contents of this file will be regenerated and all        
// manual modifications will be lost.                                         
// ************************************************************************ //

// PASTLWTR : 1.2
// File generated on 4/20/2013 7:14:17 AM from Type Library described below.


{$TYPEDADDRESS OFF} // Unit must be compiled without type-checked pointers. 
{$WARN SYMBOL_PLATFORM OFF}
{$WRITEABLECONST ON}
{$VARPROPSETTER ON}
interface

uses Windows, ActiveX, Classes, Graphics, OleCtrls, StdVCL, Variants;


// *********************************************************************//
// GUIDS declared in the TypeLibrary. Following prefixes are used:        
//   Type Libraries     : LIBID_xxxx                                      
//   CoClasses          : CLASS_xxxx                                      
//   DISPInterfaces     : DIID_xxxx                                       
//   Non-DISP interfaces: IID_xxxx                                        
// *********************************************************************//
const
  // TypeLibrary Major and minor versions
  ButtonXControl1MajorVersion = 1;
  ButtonXControl1MinorVersion = 0;

  LIBID_ButtonXControl1: TGUID = '{5285C4F5-89FE-4491-9D87-BD284C195C49}';

  IID_IButtonX: TGUID = '{0DBF599A-1513-415B-99F8-C49F023AE176}';
  DIID_IButtonXEvents: TGUID = '{F3555B69-8F22-4FEC-B088-40B02AB5311D}';
  CLASS_ButtonX: TGUID = '{1099073B-BD04-4974-BD25-C0B1C3A110F4}';

// *********************************************************************//
// Declaration of Enumerations defined in Type Library                    
// *********************************************************************//
// Constants for enum TxDragMode
type
  TxDragMode = TOleEnum;
const
  dmManual = $00000000;
  dmAutomatic = $00000001;

// Constants for enum TxMouseButton
type
  TxMouseButton = TOleEnum;
const
  mbLeft = $00000000;
  mbRight = $00000001;
  mbMiddle = $00000002;

type

// *********************************************************************//
// Forward declaration of types defined in TypeLibrary                    
// *********************************************************************//
  IButtonX = interface;
  IButtonXDisp = dispinterface;
  IButtonXEvents = dispinterface;

// *********************************************************************//
// Declaration of CoClasses defined in Type Library                       
// (NOTE: Here we map each CoClass to its Default Interface)              
// *********************************************************************//
  ButtonX = IButtonX;


// *********************************************************************//
// Declaration of structures, unions and aliases.                         
// *********************************************************************//
  PPUserType1 = ^IFontDisp; {*}


// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IButtonX
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {0DBF599A-1513-415B-99F8-C49F023AE176}
// *********************************************************************//
  IButtonX = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{0DBF599A-1513-415B-99F8-C49F023AE176}']
    function Get_Cancel: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_Cancel(Value: WordBool); safecall;
    function Get_Caption: WideString; safecall;
    procedure Set_Caption(const Value: WideString); safecall;
    function Get_Default: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_Default(Value: WordBool); safecall;
    function Get_DragCursor: Smallint; safecall;
    procedure Set_DragCursor(Value: Smallint); safecall;
    function Get_DragMode: TxDragMode; safecall;
    procedure Set_DragMode(Value: TxDragMode); safecall;
    function Get_Enabled: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_Enabled(Value: WordBool); safecall;
    function Get_Font: IFontDisp; safecall;
    procedure Set_Font(const Value: IFontDisp); safecall;
    procedure _Set_Font(var Value: IFontDisp); safecall;
    function Get_Visible: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_Visible(Value: WordBool); safecall;
    function Get_WordWrap: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_WordWrap(Value: WordBool); safecall;
    function Get_DoubleBuffered: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure Set_DoubleBuffered(Value: WordBool); safecall;
    function Get_AlignDisabled: WordBool; safecall;
    function Get_VisibleDockClientCount: Integer; safecall;
    function DrawTextBiDiModeFlagsReadingOnly: Integer; safecall;
    procedure InitiateAction; safecall;
    function IsRightToLeft: WordBool; safecall;
    function UseRightToLeftReading: WordBool; safecall;
    function UseRightToLeftScrollBar: WordBool; safecall;
    procedure SetSubComponent(IsSubComponent: WordBool); safecall;
    procedure AboutBox; safecall;
    property Cancel: WordBool read Get_Cancel write Set_Cancel;
    property Caption: WideString read Get_Caption write Set_Caption;
    property Default: WordBool read Get_Default write Set_Default;
    property DragCursor: Smallint read Get_DragCursor write Set_DragCursor;
    property DragMode: TxDragMode read Get_DragMode write Set_DragMode;
    property Enabled: WordBool read Get_Enabled write Set_Enabled;
    property Font: IFontDisp read Get_Font write Set_Font;
    property Visible: WordBool read Get_Visible write Set_Visible;
    property WordWrap: WordBool read Get_WordWrap write Set_WordWrap;
    property DoubleBuffered: WordBool read Get_DoubleBuffered write Set_DoubleBuffered;
    property AlignDisabled: WordBool read Get_AlignDisabled;
    property VisibleDockClientCount: Integer read Get_VisibleDockClientCount;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  IButtonXDisp
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {0DBF599A-1513-415B-99F8-C49F023AE176}
// *********************************************************************//
  IButtonXDisp = dispinterface
    ['{0DBF599A-1513-415B-99F8-C49F023AE176}']
    property Cancel: WordBool dispid 201;
    property Caption: WideString dispid -518;
    property Default: WordBool dispid 202;
    property DragCursor: Smallint dispid 203;
    property DragMode: TxDragMode dispid 204;
    property Enabled: WordBool dispid -514;
    property Font: IFontDisp dispid -512;
    property Visible: WordBool dispid 205;
    property WordWrap: WordBool dispid 206;
    property DoubleBuffered: WordBool dispid 207;
    property AlignDisabled: WordBool readonly dispid 208;
    property VisibleDockClientCount: Integer readonly dispid 209;
    function DrawTextBiDiModeFlagsReadingOnly: Integer; dispid 210;
    procedure InitiateAction; dispid 211;
    function IsRightToLeft: WordBool; dispid 212;
    function UseRightToLeftReading: WordBool; dispid 213;
    function UseRightToLeftScrollBar: WordBool; dispid 214;
    procedure SetSubComponent(IsSubComponent: WordBool); dispid 215;
    procedure AboutBox; dispid -552;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  IButtonXEvents
// Flags:     (0)
// GUID:      {F3555B69-8F22-4FEC-B088-40B02AB5311D}
// *********************************************************************//
  IButtonXEvents = dispinterface
    ['{F3555B69-8F22-4FEC-B088-40B02AB5311D}']
    procedure OnClick; dispid 201;
    procedure OnKeyPress(var Key: Smallint); dispid 202;
  end;


// *********************************************************************//
// OLE Control Proxy class declaration
// Control Name     : TButtonX
// Help String      : ButtonX Control
// Default Interface: IButtonX
// Def. Intf. DISP? : No
// Event   Interface: IButtonXEvents
// TypeFlags        : (38) CanCreate Licensed Control
// *********************************************************************//
  TButtonXOnKeyPress = procedure(ASender: TObject; var Key: Smallint) of object;

  TButtonX = class(TOleControl)
  private
    FOnClick: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnKeyPress: TButtonXOnKeyPress;
    FIntf: IButtonX;
    function  GetControlInterface: IButtonX;
  protected
    procedure CreateControl;
    procedure InitControlData; override;
  public
    function DrawTextBiDiModeFlagsReadingOnly: Integer;
    procedure InitiateAction;
    function IsRightToLeft: WordBool;
    function UseRightToLeftReading: WordBool;
    function UseRightToLeftScrollBar: WordBool;
    procedure SetSubComponent(IsSubComponent: WordBool);
    procedure AboutBox;
    property  ControlInterface: IButtonX read GetControlInterface;
    property  DefaultInterface: IButtonX read GetControlInterface;
    property DoubleBuffered: WordBool index 207 read GetWordBoolProp write SetWordBoolProp;
    property AlignDisabled: WordBool index 208 read GetWordBoolProp;
    property VisibleDockClientCount: Integer index 209 read GetIntegerProp;
  published
    property Anchors;
    property Cancel: WordBool index 201 read GetWordBoolProp write SetWordBoolProp stored False;
    property Caption: WideString index -518 read GetWideStringProp write SetWideStringProp stored False;
    property Default: WordBool index 202 read GetWordBoolProp write SetWordBoolProp stored False;
    property DragCursor: Smallint index 203 read GetSmallintProp write SetSmallintProp stored False;
    property DragMode: TOleEnum index 204 read GetTOleEnumProp write SetTOleEnumProp stored False;
    property Enabled: WordBool index -514 read GetWordBoolProp write SetWordBoolProp stored False;
    property Font: TFont index -512 read GetTFontProp write SetTFontProp stored False;
    property Visible: WordBool index 205 read GetWordBoolProp write SetWordBoolProp stored False;
    property WordWrap: WordBool index 206 read GetWordBoolProp write SetWordBoolProp stored False;
    property OnClick: TNotifyEvent read FOnClick write FOnClick;
    property OnKeyPress: TButtonXOnKeyPress read FOnKeyPress write FOnKeyPress;
  end;

procedure Register;

resourcestring
  dtlServerPage = 'Servers';

  dtlOcxPage = 'ActiveX';

implementation

uses ComObj;

procedure TButtonX.InitControlData;
const
  CEventDispIDs: array [0..1] of DWORD = (
    $000000C9, $000000CA);
  CTFontIDs: array [0..0] of DWORD = (
    $FFFFFE00);
  CControlData: TControlData2 = (
    ClassID: '{1099073B-BD04-4974-BD25-C0B1C3A110F4}';
    EventIID: '{F3555B69-8F22-4FEC-B088-40B02AB5311D}';
    EventCount: 2;
    EventDispIDs: @CEventDispIDs;
    LicenseKey: nil (*HR:$80040154*);
    Flags: $0000001C;
    Version: 401;
    FontCount: 1;
    FontIDs: @CTFontIDs);
begin
  ControlData := @CControlData;
  TControlData2(CControlData).FirstEventOfs := Cardinal(@@FOnClick) - Cardinal(Self);
end;

procedure TButtonX.CreateControl;

  procedure DoCreate;
  begin
    FIntf := IUnknown(OleObject) as IButtonX;
  end;

begin
  if FIntf = nil then DoCreate;
end;

function TButtonX.GetControlInterface: IButtonX;
begin
  CreateControl;
  Result := FIntf;
end;

function TButtonX.DrawTextBiDiModeFlagsReadingOnly: Integer;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.DrawTextBiDiModeFlagsReadingOnly;
end;

procedure TButtonX.InitiateAction;
begin
  DefaultInterface.InitiateAction;
end;

function TButtonX.IsRightToLeft: WordBool;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.IsRightToLeft;
end;

function TButtonX.UseRightToLeftReading: WordBool;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.UseRightToLeftReading;
end;

function TButtonX.UseRightToLeftScrollBar: WordBool;
begin
  Result := DefaultInterface.UseRightToLeftScrollBar;
end;

procedure TButtonX.SetSubComponent(IsSubComponent: WordBool);
begin
  DefaultInterface.SetSubComponent(IsSubComponent);
end;

procedure TButtonX.AboutBox;
begin
  DefaultInterface.AboutBox;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents(dtlOcxPage, [TButtonX]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: It's not necessary to put information in the subject that you can include in your tags (like `delphi`). The tag system works extremely well here, and it doesn't need any help. It's better to use the space to improve your question subject instead. Thanks. :-) (Can you [edit] to add an image or better describe the issue you're asking about? I see a ton of auto-generated code, no information about an image anywhere, and I have no idea what exactly you're asking us. What "image" is also stretched?)

Comment: My guess is to access its canvas handle and draw the image there yourself with windows api. And if I'm not mistaken, I think the speed button is Delphi, not Windows.

Comment: I am asking for someone that could specify where and what to put in the lines, yes this is a delphi activex control button, but the button has no image embeded, if there is a tbitbtn or speedbutton in activex control wizard I will used them instead of tbutton only.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to assign the image? Or will it be fixed? I'm wondering how it would be possible to expose an image property on an ActiveX control...

Comment: @Jerry Dodge,  it can be fixed or it can be assigned if possible?

Comment: Actually if it cant be done, I can use the ActiveX Form with SpeedButton and Autosize to true, but the problem is the image cant be resized and it is fixed because the form was the handle of the button during at design time.

Comment: thanks, its only a testing.  But it cant be.